# JSON Viewer that allows copying a sub-element

Tags: json

I am currently using this online [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to view JSON objects. Unfortunately, the viewer doesn't have an option to copy a sub-element. In a complex object it can be hard to manually find the closing bracket.

I'm looking for an alternative with the following requirements:

- Collapsable subelements with copying
- Web application is preferred, but I could also use a Mac app or PyCharm plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://codebeautify.org/view/jsonviewer.

1. Set result mode to "code"
2. Using the arrows to the right of the line numbers, collapse/fold the element(s) you want to copy
3. Highlight the blue arrow icon that takes the place of the code you folded and copy and paste it into a text file

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Very simple to use.

Gives you tree structure, modify it, copy it, sort it whatever you like.

After modifying it gives you you output on one click.

Go ahead try it.

Comment: Copying isn't very easy

Comment: I think it's easy just two clicks to duplicate element, also i didn't check codebeautify link sent by @Skram both websites are pretty much same when it's in tree mode, but jsononlineeditor doesn't have additional stuff like codebeautify so i think i will be using codebeautify from now on :)